# Excel Conditional Dynamic Data Validation

Tags: arrays, excel

I have a problem with the formula defining list for Data validation.

I am using an array formula in range D1:D5 to list values from B1:B5 that match criteria "Y" in column A:

=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$5,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$5="Y",ROW($A$1:$A$5),""),ROW())),"")
I name this array "myrange"

Then in E1 in Data validation I use write below formula for a list:

=OFFSET(D1;0;0;MATCH("";myrange;0)-1;1)

However, if I do the same starting not in row 1 - formula does not show correct values (some values disappear and "Y" criteria is not maintained). 
Please, help me to fix this if you know how.

PS. Above formulas come from: [Excel Conditional Dynamic Data Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090765/excel-conditional-dynamic-data-validation)

Comment: "_If I do the same starting not in row 1_", do you mean the `=IFERROR` function or the `=OFFSET` data validation?

Comment: I mean IFERROR Function.

Comment: F.E. If my ranges start in A5:A10, B5:B10 and I type formula in D5 as =IFERROR(INDEX($B$5:$B$10,SMALL(IF($A$5:$A$10="Y",ROW($A$5:$A$10),""),ROW())),"")

Comment: I get wrong values that are not in order and not matching the criteria "Y"

Answer (score 0):

The formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$5,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$5="aa",ROW($A$1:$A$5),""),ROW())),"")
```

Only works at row 1 because you are indexing using `SMALL(...,ROW())` which `ROW()` obviously returns the current row you are at.  This works great if your list starts at row 1 and works down but will break if started at row 2 or lower.

Depending on where you put the data you need to update that `ROW()` number to match the actual row that you start on.

In addition to make this formula more dynamic you can use the full column name i.e. `$E:$E` or `$B:$B` to make it so that wherever the data starts in the column this formula will pick it up.

You would need to update the formula to

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX($E:$E,SMALL(IF($D:$D="aa",ROW($D:$D),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

So instead of `ROW()` we call `ROW(A1)` which evalutates to `1` and as you autofill down since we omit the `$` it will update to `A2, A3, A4...` as such you get your nice `{1,2,3,4,5}` array as you need it.

Now remember to use ctrl+shift+enter only on the **first** entry.  Then auto-fill down and name the range.  If you select the whole range and then hit ctrl-shift-enter it will not work.

And as long as you keep `myrange` updated then your list should work fine.

Comment: Does not work for me, probably a silly mistake somewhere. I will now upload an example

Comment: @AndreyVorobyev Alright, yeah if you update your question with what you have I can update my answer accordingly

Comment: An example is here: <http://wikisend.com/download/395134/Book_ex.xlsx>
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: forgot to notify you, sry))

Comment: @AndreyVorobyev alright my answer is updated, should be working now

Comment: Yyyuuuuwhooo, it works now! @chancea, thank you so much!!!! This formula requires a lot of capacity though, I need to apply it to 5000 rows. But looks like there is no more efficient way to do it. or...?))

Answer (score 0):

So to sum it up, 
You would need to update the formula to

=IFERROR(INDEX($E:$E,SMALL(IF($D:$D="aa",ROW($D:$D),""),ROW(A1))),"")

Now remember to use ctrl+shift+enter only on the first entry. Then auto-fill down and name the range. If you select the whole range and then hit ctrl-shift-enter it will not work.

You can increase Efficiency by limiting ranges in the formula, but always start at row 1, e.g.:
=IFERROR(INDEX($E1:$E10,SMALL(IF($D1:$D10="aa",ROW($D1:$D10),""),ROW(A1))),"")    even if you type the formula in row 5,6,7...
Thank you @chancea